# list wordpress posts from current category and

Tags: php, wordpress, posts

Using this code from here: http://www.snilesh.com/resources/wordpress/wordpress-recent-posts-from-current-same-category/

```
<h3>Recently Post From Same Category</h3>
<ul>
<?php
global $post;
$category = get_the_category($post->ID);
$category = $category[0]->cat_ID;
$myposts = get_posts(array('numberposts' => 5, 'offset' => 0,
'category__in' => array($category), 'post__not_in' =>
array($post->ID),'post_status'=>'publish'));
foreach($myposts as $post) :
setup_postdata($post);
?>
<li>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<?php the_title(); ?></a>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</ul>
```

I'm able to display all the posts from the current category. What I would like to display is all the posts from the current category AND category 186.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show posts that are both in the current category **and** category 186, use `category__and` instead:

```
$myposts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => 5,
    'offset' => 0,
    'category__and' => array($category, 186),
    'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
    'post_status'=>'publish'
));
```

For more details: [WP_Query - Category Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters).

P.S.: [get_posts()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) internally uses the WP_Query class to fetch posts so its parameters are the same.